# Child Element of XML Element is "\n    " when there is a space in the XML Document?

Tags: xml, vb.net, soap

I have the following XML:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <SOAP-ENV:Header>
  </SOAP-ENV:Header>
  <SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <MessageRequest></MessageRequest>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

I am accessing the name of the child element like this:

`childNode(SOAP-ENV:Body").ChildNodes(0).Name`, but if there is  a space between elements, the child node name returns `"\n    "`, but if I remove the space I get the correct child node, for example, if there is a space between `<SOAP-ENV:Body>` and `<MessageRequest>`, the first child will return `"\n    "`, but if there is no space, it will return `<MessageRequest>`

Comment: ` the child node of the body is .` ? A dot?

Comment: no the message is long, so i just cut it off at first. I edited it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not mentioning the language you are using, but based on [your profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/33690/xaisoft?tab=questions), the [name of the `ChildNodes` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnode.childnodes.aspx) and indexing with round brackets instead of square brackets, I think VB.NET?

This situation can happen if you are using a document that [preserves white space](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.preservewhitespace.aspx). A DOM parser works at a node level. Each component of the XML is a node. You can have a text node, a CDATA node, an element node etc. These will get picked up by the `ChildNodes` property and the number of children will vary.

**Check [the node types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnodetype) of the nodes you are working with.**

If you have indented elements then that indentation (spaces, line feed etc) becomes the first child. Remove formatting and the first child should be an element child.

Comment: This is exactly what it was.  Is there a way around this were I don't have to move indentations, etc?  Thanks.

Comment: I tried PreserveWhiteSpace = False and IgnoreWhiteSpace = True for XmlReaderSettings, but it still does not work.

Comment: @Xaisoft: When using a DOM parser, which as I said works with nodes, your best bet is to perform actions based on the node type. You verify the node type (e.g. element) and if it is of the expected type do something, else do something else or ignore it all together. Using a web service framework would spare you from doing low level XML manipulations like that.